# Profiling C++ with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, macos, memory

is it possible to profile C++ apps with Xcode so one gets;

- memory leaks like with valgrind
- possible errors before running the program

Thanks, I am very new to mac and xcode

Where can one find a good tutorial for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding memory leaks, run XCode and then launch `Start with Performance Tool` -> `Leaks`

Alternatively and necessarily for old pre-Panther users of XCode, it is possible to debug with guard `malloc`, detailed explanation in the Mac development docs, but [here is a quick walk-through](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/01/10/using-malloc-to-debug-memory-misuse-in-cocoa/).

Comment: Walk through link in your answer (http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease) does not work anymore.

Answer (score 9):

You have a tool called [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), a free Apple tool included in XCode, that catches most of those errors.

Comment: Does Instruments have an NSZombie equivalent for C++? Getting notified immediately when a released object is messaged is incredibly powerful.

Answer (score 4):

Instruments is a great tool, as @pau.estalella says. Valgrind support for Mac OS X is now in the main Valgrind repository, courtesy of Greg Parker.

Comment: Valgrind is indeed the greatest memory checking tool. Hopefully some day there will be DMGs available for Mac OS X.

Comment: @pau.estalella You can install valgrind via MacPorts (which does have an installer that you can get via download).

Answer (score 2):

> possible errors before running the program

Xcode 3.2 now comes with static analysis tool powered by [Clang](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), which will detect *logical* errors such as unreleased memory at compile time.

It is just in Build > Build and Analyze menu.

Read [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/index.html) to get more detail.

Comment: The Clang Static Analyzer can't deal with C++ yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit outside my current core competencies, but I've spotted a tool called Shark on my Mac which offers profiling and optimisation support.  There are other Xcode tools too.  But I've not yet used any of them for real.  And I have no experience of valgrind on the Mac.

Not much of an answer, I know.

Comment: great thanks

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001410-CH205-BCIIHAAJ